Google Cloud Reserving Specific External IP Address
I need to reserve a specific IP address such as 35.123.123.12 in GCP. GCP is using dynamic IP allocation but I just want to learn if there is any way to get a specific IP address which belongs to Google.

It is not possible to reserve a specific IP address that belongs to Google because Googles IP address pool is dynamic and managed by them.
